# flutter:Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8

Tags: java, flutter, android-studio, java-11

I am trying to develop a app using flutter, when I enter ../gradlew signingreport, it returns am error:
[image]

Then I check the problem on Google and I can not change the Java version because I can not find the location as it shows below:
[image]

There is no option for me to change the version of Java, so what should I do?

Comment: @MartinZeitler Thanks for your reply, I see the answoer, but the problem is I can not find the path of the gradle Jdk dropdown area, I can find the grade from seeting->Build,Exeution,Deployment->Build Tools-->Gradle. But when I click the Gradle button, there is no Gradle  JDK dropdown shown on the right.

Comment: You're referring to an outdated answer, while there are two pages of answers.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Thanks! I have solved the problem, because android studio can not show the correct version all the time, so I use windows powershell to run the command and it works successfully!

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Kindly upgrade your java version